# ListItem Selection in a ModalPopupExtender doesn't work in Google Chrome

Tags: html, asp.net, ajax, google-chrome, visual-studio-2008

i have a Problem in Google Chrome with a ListItem which is in a ModalPopupExtender.

When i set a PopupDraghandlerControlID to move the Panel then i can't select the Items in the List. When I start the Page without the PopupDragHandlerControlID it works.

It Just happens in Google Chrome! Firefox and Internet Explorer is working fine.

Who can help me with the Problem?

Here is my full sourcecode:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .modalBackground
        {
            background-color: Black;
            filter: alpha(opacity=90);
            opacity: 0.8;
        }
        .modalPopup
        {
            background-color: #FFFFFF;
            border-width: 3px;
            border-style: solid;
            border-color: black;
            padding-top: 10px;
            padding-left: 10px;
            width: 300px;
            height: 140px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body style = "height:3000px">
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:Button ID="btnShow" runat="server" Text="Show Modal Popup" />

<!-- ModalPopupExtender -->
<cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="mp1" runat="server" PopupControlID="Panel1" TargetControlID="btnShow"
    CancelControlID="btnClose" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" PopupDragHandleControlID="Panel1">
</cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup" align="center" style = "display:none">
    This is an ASP.Net AJAX ModalPopupExtender Example<br />
                                        <asp:ListBox id="drop1" rows="5" runat="server">
<asp:ListItem selected="true">Item 1</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Item 2</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Item 3</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Item 4</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Item 5</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Item 6</asp:ListItem>
</asp:ListBox>
    <asp:Button ID="btnClose" runat="server" Text="Close" />
</asp:Panel>
<!-- ModalPopupExtender -->
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Screenshot]